# Why does pressing Ctrl-backslash result in core dump?

Tags: python, coredump, backslash, ctrl

When I'm in a python application (the python shell, for instance), pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> results in

```
>>> Quit (core dumped)
```

Why is this, and how can I avoid this?
It is very inconvenient if application bails out whenever I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> by accident.

Comment: For me it only quits, but does not dump. I don't know why it quits in the first place, but that it dumps core might indicate a problem with your python installation.

Comment: `CTRL + \ ` is a default shortcut for sending `SIGQUIT` to foreground process. By default, `SIGQUIT` causes a core dump. More in `man kill`. If you wish, you can remove the shortcut from your terminal perferences.

Comment: That's weird, because it doesn't happen when I'm in nano or vim for instance.

Comment: Nano and Vim take special care to intercept ^C, ^Z and ^\. Most programs accept the default behavior, as Python does.

Comment: It breaks `sudo` on my machine because quitting `ipython` this way changes the output of `stty`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The python module `signal` is convenient to deal with this.

```
import signal

# Intercept ctrl-c, ctrl-\ and ctrl-z
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    pass
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal_handler)
```

Just add handlers to the signal that (in this case) do nothing.

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> is the Linux key that generates the `QUIT` signal. Generally, that signal causes a program to terminate and dump core. This is a feature of UNIX and Linux, wholly unrelated to Python. (For example, try `sleep 30` followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>.)

If you want to disable that feature, use the [stty](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) command.

From the Linux command line, before Python starts:

```
stty quit undef
```

Comment: while this works for the python shell, ipython still quits even though `quit` has been `undef`ed